# Connect with openssl to google server but unable to get local issuer certificate. Why?

Tags: openssl, trusted-root-certificates

Trying to connect to **imap.google.com:993** with **openssl**.

1) downloaded CAfile in encoded DER format from https://pki.goog/ . The file called [GTS Root R1](https://pki.goog/gtsr1/GTSR1.crt)

2) converted this file into PEM format

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in GTSR1.crt -out googleRootCA.pem
```

3) connect to imap.gmail.com:993 and use this googleRootCA.pem file

```
openssl.exe s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -CAfile ./googleRootCA.pem
```

But openssl reports:
**Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)**

Why?
Its an official root CA from google so it should work?!
OS: Windows 10

Comment: I've just did according to the step by step on your post and it works well in my *Ubuntu Desktop Ubuntu 20.04 LTS*. Add up on your question from which **OS and its version** you are run those commands.

Comment: @jluizsouzadev: the OS only matters if you use an OS-supplied package, which is not universal on any OS and not even possible on some. In particular `openssl.exe` suggests Windows, and there is no Microsoft supplied package of OpenSSL but there are at least hundreds of third-party ones, and the main ones I know of (like upstream) don't include CA certs, leaving that up to you. Ubuntu's package does include several GlobalSign roots, and installs in `-CApath` format which is NOT overridden by the OP's command and thus still used even though the `-CAfile` data is inapplicable and unused.

Comment: OP: if you're using a build of OpenSSL that doesn't include CA certs, such as but not only slproweb for Windows, consider using the OpenSSL-format Mozilla bundle [supplied by the curl project](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) rather than going around one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its an official root CA from google so it should work?!

It's *an* official google root, but it's not the *correct* one.

Look at *all* the output from `openssl s_client`:

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -CAfile GTSR1.pem
CONNECTED(00000094)
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=imap.gmail.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
---
Server certificate
[snipped -- irrelevant]
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3216 bytes and written 261 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
[snipped except]
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

Note the intermediate cert (numbered 1 in the chain display) has issuer (`i:`)

```
/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
```

That's the root labelled 'GS Root R2' (not GTS) in the webpage which [links here](https://pki.goog/gsr2/GSR2.crt), and using that file converted to PEM works:

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -CAfile GSR2.pem -quiet
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = imap.gmail.com
verify return:1
* OK Gimap ready for requests from [redacted]
```

Also, the openssl error tells you the *intermediate* (aka subordinate) CA used is GTS CA 1O1, and that same webpage shows that GTS CA 1O1 is under GS Root 2, not GTS Root 1.
[image: part of https://pki.goog]